# Aggregate Function Confusion

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have a table with a list of products, schema is:

```
Product, Warehouse, Supplier, Order Quantity
```

What I want to do is for each supplier, select the warehouse that has the most order quantity.

Table Data:

```
Cornflakes, WH1, Kellogs, 10
Cornflakes, WH2, Kellogs, 5
Cornflakes, WH3, Kellogs, 0
Crunchy,    WH1, Cadbury, 20
Crunchy,    WH2, Cadbury, 10
Mars,       WH1, Cadbury. 56
Mars,       WH4, Cadbury, 8
```

I think there is enough information here to provide easy answer, if there is not please ask me for clarification in a comment rather than downvote and I will edit question very quickly.

Sample Output:

```
Kellogs, WH1
Cadbury, WH1
```

Warehouse number will be this one because it has the most total quantity to order for every product under that supplier.

Comment: Can you give a sample output of what you want. That'll help clear the question.

Comment: Done, thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS SQL 2008+

```
SELECT Supplier, Warehouse
FROM (
  SELECT Warehouse, Supplier, rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Supplier ORDER BY SUM([Order Quantity]) DESC)
  FROM t
  GROUP BY Warehouse, Supplier
) tt
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: That's genius! It works! I'm going to reformat a little but the logic is sound. Just a side note, you have a syntax error, PARTITION BY and ORDER BY in an OVER clause are NOT separated by a comma.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just did not think of ROW NUMBER at all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
select a.supplier,a.warehouse,a.max(Order Quantity) from
(select supplier,warehouse,sum(Order Quantity) as quantity from products
group by supplier,warehouse)a
 group by a.supplier,a.warehouse
```

Comment: No good, syntax error: Cannot find either column "a" or the user-defined function or aggregate "a.max", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: I corrected the column names according to my actual query. You have a syntax error in your answer. a.MAX is a syntax problem, it cannot exist!